# How to line up two side images and one bigger image & keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up two images on the right side with the main image on the left and for the side images to be lined up at the top and bottom. Like in this image:

[image]

The code below is a simplified version of what i'm trying. The difficulty I'm having is that I can't line up the top edge and bottom edge of the wrapper to be exact with no overflow of the images and to stay lined up **while preserving the aspect ratio when I resize the window**.  Is there any way to have it scale up to those perfect borders correctly and resize all 3 images keeping their aspect ratio in relation to screen size?

Also, do the images have to be some kind of specific dimensions for this to work?

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel{
    position: relative;
    background-color:crimson;
    float: left;
    width: 78%;
}

.side-images{
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.img-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.carousel-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img1{
    background-color:darkgoldenrod;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img2{
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

body{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="carousel">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" class="carousel-img">
    </div>
    <div class="side-images">
        <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img1">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img2">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try giving the side images half the height of the *main* image. Give the images the following style: `object-fit: cover`. This will make the image stay the same height and have the image 'cover' the given height. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider the fact that you know the aspect ratio of the bigger image and you will always have square images on the right side you can then do some maths. On the left side we need to have `HeightL/WidthL = Ratio`. On the right side we need to have `HeightR = 2 * WidthR`. We also have `HeightL=HeightR` and `widthL + widthR = 100%`.

From this we obtain:

```
WidthL = 200%/(Ratio + 2)
HeightL = (Ratio*100%)/(Ratio + 2)
```

In your example we have `Ratio = 0.75`

```css
.carousel {
  float: left;
  width: calc(200%/2.75);
}

.side-images {
  float: left;
  width: calc((0.75*100%)/2.75);
}

.img-wrapper{
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" class="carousel-img">
  </div>
  <div class="side-images">
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img1">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img2">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That you can simplify using flexbox where you need only one formula:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
.carousel {
  width: calc(200%/2.75);
}

.side-images {
   flex-grow:1;
   flex-basis:0%;
}

.img-wrapper{
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" class="carousel-img">
  </div>
  <div class="side-images">
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img1">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any" class="img2">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In case the right image will not be square we can add more math and instead of `HeightR = 2 * WidthR` we will have `HeightR = 2 * RatioR * WidthR` where `RatioR` is the ratio of the right images and we will get

```
 WidthL = (200% * RatioR)/(Ratio + 2*RatioR)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
.carousel {
  width: calc((200% * 1.6)/(0.75 + 2*1.6));
}

.side-images {
   flex-grow:1;
   flex-basis:0%;
}

.img-wrapper{
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" class="carousel-img">
  </div>
  <div class="side-images">
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/480/any" class="img1">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/150/240/any" class="img2">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if we suppose we will have 3 images all with different ratio then the formula will be:

```
WidthL = (100% * (R1 + R2) )/(R + R1 + R2)
```

Where `R` is the ratio of the big Image and `R1`,`R2` the ratio of the right images:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
.carousel {
  width: calc((100% * (0.5 + 1.6))/(0.75 + 0.5 + 1.6));
}

.side-images {
   flex-grow:1;
   flex-basis:0%;
}

.img-wrapper{
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" class="carousel-img">
  </div>
  <div class="side-images">
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/300/480/any" class="img1">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/100/any" class="img2">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-image">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any">
        </div>
        <div class="side-image">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any">
            </a>
            <a href="#" >
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/480/480/any">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 600px;
}
.main-image{
    width: 80%;
}
.main-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.side-image{
    width: 20%;
}
.side-image img{
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
}
  I set a max-height:600px you can change whatever you want.
```

Comment: Hi htmldevmate, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will keep the images their original ratio..

Comment: you can change the max -height that I set . then the image will take the original ratio.

Comment: the question asks for preserving the aspect ratio when resizing the window